# 9.1.1 CM Install stops when import key fails

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

Ok so for our `9.1.1 XP1` installation, so far we have the following roles installed:

**For xConnect/xDB server:**

- XConnectCollection
- XConnectCollectionSearch
- XConnectReferenceData
- QA.XConnectMarketingAutomation
- XConnectMarketingAutomationReporting

**For Reporting/Processing server:**

- SitecoreReporting
- SitecoreProcessing

**For CM server:**

- IdentityServer

SIF is giving me this error when installing the CM role (SitecoreCM).  I'm not sure what's going on (DBA is stumped as well), if the installation is trying to put the key in SQL Server, or if it's trying to get the key from SQL Server.  Also is this a permissions error?  The SQL Server user account has the sysadmin server role and is db_owner of the databases created.

**Error:** Errors occurred while modeling the target database.  Deployment cannot continue.

Error count: 1.

**Error Code:** ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD

**More Information:**  An error occurred during deployment plan generation.  Deployment cannot continue.

Error SQL72018:  Database Encryption key could not be imported but one or more of these objects exist in your source.

[image]

Comment: You forgot `sp_configure ‘contained database authentication’, 1;
GO

RECONFIGURE;
GO`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mark, but we had already done that.  We finally figured out that it was caused by using the same database user for all databases.  It's only a problem with the CM install because that one actually creates two users in the core db.  Once I changed the json to use different user names for coreuser and securityuser the installation continued through all the database and file operations to the next error where SIF can't connect to the site to run some aspx file.  If we don't get through that one quickly I'll be posting again :)